# Why has Spring duplicate fields in Authentication and UserDetails?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

While implementing some security aspects with Spring Security, I have noticed that both [`Authentication`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) and [`UserDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) have duplicate methods like `getAuthorities`, `getCredentials` and so forth.

What is the objective behind this? It seems like a useless redundancy to me.

Edit: Since people are too lazy to check the signatures. Both interfaces have same methods. I am not referring to that `getCredentials` and `getAuthorities` are the same. Why the heck make people that assumption?

Comment: I am surprised about this as well, and I don't see a good explanation. I implemented a custom AuthenticationProvider and in the `authenticate()` method I have to return this: `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new User(username,password, AUTHORITIES),password,AUTHORITIES);`

Comment: After a few examinations of Spring security, I consider it like this:
`Authentication` is solely used by Spring Security. `UserDetails` is intended for the client code only. Due to different coding dates they intersect someway. So keep in mind that `Authentication` is not for you. Hopefully they will clean it up in Spring Security 3.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UserDetails` is *not* used for security purposes, it is just a "user info" bean. Spring Security uses `Authentication` instances. So `Authentication` instance will usually have only the information needed to let users log in (usernames, credentials and roles, basically). `UserDetails` is more generic, and can include anything related to user management (such as contact information, account information, photographs, whatever).

Typically, you will have an `Authentication` instance backed by a `UserDetails` instance.

Comment: Seems to be it but I was still able to find severals call of `UserDetails#getPassword` in a few Spring classes. I guess this is legacy. The `UserDetails` class is not as generic as the `Authentication` class.

Answer (score -2):

```
getAuthorities
```

Used for role-based security. It is often useful feature in SpringSecurity.

```
getCredentials
```

Used to get password or hashed password to chek if principal is correct. Also needful method in security.

If you sure, you dont need this features, you can override this methods with empty ones.